# How to change or add or delete Add-ins in UFT/QTP while recording

Tags: automation, qtp, hp-uft

How to change or add or delete Add-ins in UFT while recording of an application to automate

Answer (score 1):

Addins in UFT are determined when UFT is launched, to change the active add-ins you need to restart UFT and do it in the addin manager.

Answer (score 0):

Like Motti said it. But you can remove add ins on UFT go to File - Settings - Properties - Associated add-ins - modify.

Don't forget u can remove only to disassociated, not add.